Why did so few changes occur in "Pre-Proto-Germanic"?
Proto-Germanic is dated pretty late. Grimm's Law, the first and defining change, is dated to 500 BC. However, the dialects are supposed to have split up throughout the 3rd millennia BC. This would make you think that the intermediate language, Pre-Proto-Germanic, would have a lot of changes, as it spans over a thousand years. However these are the only changes I could identify:

Laryngeals > schwa when not lost
Velars merge with following w to become labiovelars
Labiovelars next to u or t are delabialized
Final e, a, o lost.

There are some earlier developments, but these surely must have happened when it was still intelligible with the rest of the PIE world (e.g. coloring by Laryngeals, Centumization, loss of Laryngeals). Assuming that it stopped being intelligible by 2000 BC, which is quite late, only having 4 major (?) changes over 1500 years seems wrong to me.
Does anybody have any information on the dating of these changes, and why it changed so slowly?

note that there are more changes, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language#Phonological_stages_from_Proto-Indo-European_to_end_of_Proto-Germanic

also note that some of the changes you give are (almost certainly) PIE, and not specific to Germanic. In particular vocalisation of laryngeals between (non-syllabic non-initial) consonants and delabialisation of labiovelars adjacent to u or w appear to have been universal

@Tristan I know there are more changes, but they are almost all not specific to Germanic -- I thought that "leftover laryngeals > schwa" is a specific change, so that's where I cut it off

the specific resolution of syllabic resonants, shortening of geminates after long vowels/diphthongs, overlengthening of final long vowels, and Cowgill's Law are all pretty much specific to Germanic. Also, whilst many of the other changes are shared with other branches, there is variation in which changes other branches have, indicating that they likely occurred as waves within a dialect continuum rather than following a strict tree

@Tristan This was my thought exactly, but when do you think the "dialect continuum" ends? I would say at least after 2000 BC it wouldn't be a dialect continuum anymore. Proto-Germanic was supposed to have been spoken continuously in the Nordic Bronze Age culture (c. 1750 BC) so it was definitely not a dialect continuum by then...right
